# How can I dynamically change the height of a div to match the size of the div containing it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got div1 and div2 with div2 containing div1 (and some other elements). I want to dynamically  change the height of div1 to match the height of div2(- the height of the other elements) whenever div1 exceeds that height. The reason I don't just set div1's height outright is because div2's size isn't fixed and I want the horizontal scroll bar from div1 to stick to the bottom of its content and not to the bottom of div2.

I don't have any code to show since it's just two divs.

If it helps, div1 will contain a table.

Here's what I got so far:

```
if(document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight > document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight) {       
    document.getElementById("div1").style.height = document.getElementById("div1").parentNode.offsetHeight+"px";
    document.getElementById("div1").style.overflowY = "scroll";                             
}
```

This works for setting the overflow but I can't get it to actually change the height of div1

Here's the working version:

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.height = '';
document.getElementById("div1").style.overflowY = "";   
if(document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight > document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight) {   
    var height = document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight - document.getElementById("other_data").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("div1").style.height = parseInt(height)+"px";
    document.getElementById("div1").style.overflowY = "scroll";                             
}
```

for those who might be having the same problem.

Comment: Can you use css `min-height` property? It allows you to do what you need.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the scale changes automatically when you don't set any size atts?

Comment: @Samich I don't see how it would help. I don't know the height of div2 before I actually load it, and it changes afterwards. Besides, using min-height on div1 will keep the scroll bar permanently at the bottom of div2.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov yes, it does, but if I don't set anything and div1 becomes bigger than div2, the scroll bar also shifts down and I need it to not go further than the bottom of div2. I might link a picture to explain how I want it to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work.  You can write an event listener to watch for page resize, of if you're dynamically changing the size of the "parent" div tag, you should just call the js code to resize the child div each time.

HTML:

```
<div id=div1><div id=div2></div></div>
```

JS:

```
div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
div2.style.height = div2.parentNode.offsetHeight+"px"
```

Comment: but how can I reliably check if div1 is taller than div2? can I do it by comparing offsetHeight? like `if(document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight > document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight)`

Comment: the "if" works alright but I just can't resize the div. It just adds the scroll bar (see example) but doesn't change the size of the div.

Comment: okay another update. `div2.style.height = div2.parentNode.offsetHeight+"px"` doesn't work, however something like `div2.style.height = '500px'` works. I have no idea how that makes any sense

Comment: console.alert(div2.parentNode.offsetHeight) and make sure you're getting an integer.  If not, try inspecting the object using the console and seeing why it's not returning a value.  The console on WebKit browser (chrome and safari) is super helpful.

Comment: you can turn off scroll bars (if you want) by setting the overflow css property on the object you don't want scrollbars on.