# can we dynamically position a label after dynamic binding of a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView which contains the monthly attendance of employees, department wise, and is binded dynamically according to the department code. The number of rows varies, as the departments have different number of emoployees. I have to place a label after the GridView has binded. Is it possible

Comment: Everything is possible.

Comment: Then will you please explain how?

Answer (score 0):

You can put paging in the grid and put label after it, it will adjust position dynamically

Comment: I don't want to do paging.

Comment: You can put grid inside the <div>/table then place your label after it.

Comment: Tried but to no benefit.

Comment: Have you put proper CSS in <div>?

Comment: I used table but that wasn't any good. How to use CSS for this, please explain.

Comment: You set div height dynamically by using javascript or jquery, see this for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326273/how-can-i-dynamically-change-the-height-of-a-div-to-match-the-size-of-the-div-co